# UIRotationGestureRecognizer rotation sometimes bumps to very large value

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I'm using a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` to rotate a `UIImageView`. By adding all small rotation changes to a `CGFloat`, I try to calculate the total rotation of the `UIImageView`. It does fine, but somehow the `rotation` property of the gesture sometimes has a very large value. Normally, when rotating slow, it sits around 0.00##, but then it suddenly starts giving values like 6.##. The end result is a total of > 300 radians, which is ridiculous - over 47 'revolutions' for just a millimeter worth of finger movement.

Does anyone know what causes this, and more importantly, have a solution to it?

Here's some code:

```
if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
{
    totalRotation += [gesture rotation];
    NSLog(@"%f", [gesture rotation]);

    [gesture view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[gesture view] transform], [gesture rotation]);

    [gesture setRotation:0];
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"rot: %f", totalRotation);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting this too.  The 6.## values are around 2 * PI (ie 360 degrees).  Can be +/- 6.## in my experience.  I've even got +/- 12.## (4 * PI)  Rather than spending time working out why, I'm just checking and correcting:

```
CGFloat useRotation = gesture.rotation;

while( useRotation < -M_PI )
    useRotation += M_PI*2;

while( useRotation > M_PI )
    useRotation -= M_PI*2;
```

Actually you shouldn't need to do this because you are using the angle directly.  Sin(angle +/- PI*2) = Sin(angle) etc.  Don't worry about the 300 radians, it will still get the transform right.  But I'm dividing the angle by 2 so this was a problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it looks like you're right. I kinda had a solution same as yours, by taking the modulo of the rotation for M_PI/180. What's left is a valid angle in radians, without all the extra revolutions.

Comment: I'd really love to figure this one out. I have a view that can be rotated by a rotation gesture. To give more "fine tuned" rotation I was dividing the rotation angle by 2. However, `(2pi + delta)/2` gives `pi + delta/2` which causes my view to flip 180 degrees for every UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged event... super annoying

Comment: Yes I see what you are doing.  Pretty sure there is no fix other than correcting gesture.rotation as above.  I didn't use modulo because I wasn't sure whether it is a float operator as well as integer but if it is, better to use it.